# Sample Autocovariance

Tags: mean, autocorrelation

Suppose that we have a wide sense stationary process $X_t$.

Without loss of generalization assuming that mean is 0, lag one covariance is $\mathbb{E}[X_t X_{t-1}]$.

In order to estimate the covariance, I use the sample version:

$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_1^N X_t X_{t-1}$$

What's bothering me here is the consecutive products i.e. $X_t X_{t-1}$ and $X_{t-1} X_{t-2}$ are not independent due to the shared $X_{t-1}$ component.

It looks like this is a mean of non-IID samples.

**Question:** Is this something to worry about?

What are some issues to be careful about (especially for the small sample case)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We need the stochastic process $\{Z_t\} = \{X_tX_{t-1}\}$ to have a constant mean  *and* be "ergodic for the mean".

If these properties hold then the Birkhoff–Khinchin Ergodic Theorem states that

$$\frac 1T \sum Z_t \to_p \mu_z = \text{Cov}(X_t,X_{t-1})$$

Let $\gamma_k \equiv E(X_tX_{t-k})$ . If

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} |\gamma_k|< +\infty$$

then the process $\{X_t\}$ is ergodic for the mean.

Assume that it is. Then continuous transformations of $\{X_t\}$ are also ergodic for the mean. Then (to be a little pedantic), $W_t \equiv LX_t = X_{t-1}$ is ergodic for the mean because the transformation induced by the lag operator is continuous. Also, multiplication and addition are continuous transformations. Then

$$Z_t = X_t \cdot W_t = X_tX_{t-1}$$

is ergodic for the mean.

Moreover, $\{Z_t\}$ has a constant mean since

$$E(Z_t) = E(X_tX_{t-1}) = \text{Cov}(X_t,X_{t-1}) = \gamma_1$$

which is constant and does not depend on the index $t$, due to $\{X_t\}$ being covariance-stationary.

So for asymptotic consistency of the sample covariance, the essential condition is the absolute summability condition on the autocovariance series of $\{X_t\}$.

I note that the fact that autocovariances of $\{X_t\}$ "do not depend on the index only on the distance", does not make them absolutely summable. We can conceive of a situation (although perhaps counter-intuitive both from a space-perspective and from a time-perspective), in which as the distance increases, the autocovariance increases also.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting take on my somewhat vague question. When we look at the autocorrelation structure of $Z_t$ for some process $X_t$, it is very likely to find significant terms due to the dependency. Basically what I am trying to ask is why don't we have an estimator that takes this into account instead of simple mean estimator?

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc Informally speaking, existence of dependence may be good for prediction - but it is bad for estimation, since it reduces the information contained in the sample. That said, we "automatically" take it into account, because the variability of our $Z$ sample is partly "self-induced/explained".